# Is logout supposed to be sticky until explicit login?

Tags: discussion, login, logout

A couple weeks ago I logged out of a site that I wasn't expecting to use again, and also revoked Google's OpenID authorization (just being tidy).  Yesterday I followed a link from chat to that site and it auto-logged me in (no prompt, no password challenge, and apparently approval from Google?).  This isn't a *complaint*, but I am puzzled by what happened.

What is logging out supposed to mean, with respect to future visits to that site?  I expected to come in as a not-logged-in user.

(All of this was in Firefox, but on two different machines.)

Comment: Probably because you are logged in with the same OpenID in other site.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd But if you explicitly revoke the OpenID authorization, should that still happen?

Comment: Right, I was (continuously) logged in on other sites, but I expected the OpenID revocation to be relevant.

Comment: Sorry, not really sure about all this, but [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68001/152859) might shed some light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. StackAuth auto logs you in if you have an account on the site and you're logged in to SE somewhere else.

Revoking the Google authorization won't do anything. The StackAuth login is done via [StackAuth.com](http://stackauth.com/), and doesn't contact Google at any point (otherwise you'd be asked to login to Google).

Comment: I suspected as much and even said that in my last comment but wasn't sure enough so edited it out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  I was expecting to be asked to log in to Google.